# Do we have better than ...?

Tags: grammar, structure

Is this a correct sentence? I have searched it in google but nothing was found

> Do we have better than ELL (a noun)?

Comment: .What is  your doubt?   Do we  have  a better  word or site  than  ELL?

Comment: For example "Do we have better than this song?"

Comment: You should  say  do we  have  a better song than this ( song)

Comment: .Are you  satisfied with  the explanation?

Comment: .Then you  can accept my answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not  know what you mean.

If  you are talking about  a site, you may say.

> **Do we have a better site than ELL**?

Comment: I do not find any reason for the down vote.My answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly understandable, but does sound truncated. A better version would be '...a better one than X'; here a better 'what' is still not defined but should be apparent from the context of the conversation.

A more formal context might dictate that you define the 'what', such as '..a better site design than ELL'.